# WatchKit Notification: view cut off on 38mm Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, push-notification, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm having a bug with our custom long look interface of push notifications on the Apple Watch, that our custom view is **cut off** before the content is completely displayed. This happens only on the 38mm device. On the 42mm device and in simulator (both sizes), our view is displayed fully (see screenshots below).

[image: Cut off on 38mm]  [image: Fine on 42mm]

The view hierarchy is like this: the root level is a big vertical `WKInterfaceGroup`. It contains labels as well as a smaller horizontal `WKInterfaceGroup`. The smaller group contains an image and a label.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Are there any ways to fix this? I'm assuming this is a bug in the WatchOS itself...

Answer (score 1):

It *is* a WatchOS bug! This only happens on WatchOS 1.0.

After upgrading to WatchOS v1.0.1, the bug disappeared and the view is displayed properly on the 38mm Watch.